# Comparison Statitics

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, survey, paired-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have 100 respondents from whom I have collected trip data for 3 months. I dont have control group or base condition.

I want to measure if the proportion of aggressive trip (Trips with atleast one aggressive event) vary between

1. Weekday and weekend
2. Morning and evening
3. Low vs high speed trip
4. Male and female
5. Teen and adults

Can I use the dependent Paired t-test or Wilcoxon rank test (my data is nonnormal) for all?

Comment: One approach may be to arrange the data into a contingency table of counts: Yes-aggressive / No-agressive on one axis and e.g. Weekday / Weekend on the other axis. From there you could use a test like chi-square test of association.

Comment: If that makes sense for your data, you might update your question with you data arranged in this way.

Comment: You also might look at *cross tabulation*, which might provide some insight.

Comment: I think I cannot use Chi-sq test as the data is not independent. I have multiple trips from the same users.

Comment: It sounds like your dependent measurement is essentially dichotomous, so tests like *t* test or Wilcoxon won't make sense.  One approach is to use logistic regression.  If I understand your data, I don't think there's any simple test that would handle the structure of this data.

Comment: But in any case, you should give more details on the structure of your data.  For example, if you have the same number of measurements for each respondent, and several measurements for each respondent, it would make sense to treat the count of aggressive incidents as the dependent variable (because the total trips per respondent is the same).  If this were the case, different analyses would be available.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the data is Naturalistic, so I don't have the same number of trips for all respondents. Thats why I am thinking of using the percentage of aggressive trips per driven mile or per trip as the dependent variable.

I think I can use Wilcoxon rank test for testing weekday/weekend or morning/evening etc and Chi-sq test for male/female test.

Comment: As you say, depending on your data, it may make sense to calculate the percentage for each respondent, and then treat those as independent observations.  I'm not sure why you are thinking about using Wilcoxon for one question and chi-square for another....